# Django send one email for changes to multiple related model instances

Tags: python, django

I have a django project in which I have a model with a foreign key to a custom user, e.g.:

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The blog entries for a particular author can be viewed and edited inline in the admin. An admin user can decide to publish blog entries by changing the 'is_published' field.

I would like to notify the user when their blog entry is published with an email. This is easy enough with an override of the save method on BlogEntry. However, multiple blog entries may be published at the same time and I only want to notify them only once, with a list of all their blog entries that have been changed from `is_published = False` to `is_published = True` in that clicking of save on the author model.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways.

If you have a way of batch publishing in your UI, simply call a function on batch publish which takes a list of blog posts to publish, and then publishes those blog posts and sends a single email.

If what you are really looking for is a summary of blog publications for a certain time period, you will want to look into setting up a periodic task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and creating a task which sends a single email for all of the published blog posts within a time period. You will need to add a publication time on your model. For example, if you wanted a daily summary of publication events, you could create a daily task which gets all blog posts published in the past day grouped by users, and then sends a single email to each user if they had a blog post published that day.

Another way you could accomplish this using Celery is to create a send email task on the first blog post save to be sent in x number of minutes. Future saves within x minutes see that there is an event in the queue and do not create another event. When x minutes are up, Celery will run the send email task, which grabs all of the tasks from the past x minutes and sends an email.

Hopefully one of these fits your requirements!